# New ceiling fan socket with copper wiring

Tags: wiring, ceiling-fan, copper, aluminum

I am trying to replace the lightbulb socket in a ceiling fan fixture.  The wires coming from the fan are aluminum (I assume bec the wires are silver colored) the wires that came with the new socket are copper.  The wires on the old socket were aluminum.  I couldn't find a new socket with aluminum wiring.  Is it safe to connect the copper to the aluminum wires or do I need to replace the whole ceiling fan?

Comment: A photo would help but it's unlikely that the wires you are referring to are Aluminum.  They are probably tinned copper stranded wires which is commonly used in lamps and similar fixtures.

Comment: I agree, aluminum wire is not legal inside lamps like that, UL White Book etc.  And there's no money savings for aluminum anyway, at that size 95% of the wire cost is insulation and labeling, mineral value is trivial.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I'm not sure how to post a picture here.  Anyway to tell if it is tinned copper wiring?

Comment: Ok, I was able to scrape the wire strands with a jackknife and could see a copper color underneath.  Thanks for both of your answers.  I had never heard of tinned copper and am much less anxious about installing the new socket.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### This is not aluminum, but *tinned copper* instead

There is no reason to use aluminum at such small wiring sizes; what you see instead on such finer-stranded *fixture wires* is *tinned* copper.  This is done to allow it to be easily used in applications where it needs to be soldered (say to a circuit board in a dimmer or fan receiver), and has none of the termination issues that actual aluminum wire does.